# Connecting two computers without server

Tags: networking, internet, python, sharing

I have a computer in my home and other in my friend's home. Both have internet access. I want to connect both computers through internet and use it for file sharing or exchange data. I dont want to use any other 3rd party series. Is it possible to use python script to do so?

Comment: Prerequisite questions: 1) Are either of your ISPs using CGNAT? (Look at the "WAN IP" shown by router, compare it to what's shown by websites.) 2) Do both of your ISPs provide IPv6 access? 3) Do you have an existing Python script in mind, or are you just planning to write one? (For file sharing, it's going to be easier to use already existing host software.)

Comment: I think this would be extremely unwise, because I don't think you have the expertise to secure a home-made solution. Get Dropbox or Mega. They won't compromise your security.

Comment: ok. short answer, yes this is entirely possible, but probably not without third party software. the technology you are looking for is a VPN. yes if you are a very skilled development team, you could write a VPN client, that would allow you to connect securely to systems in the know remote network, but most people would recommend you download a VPN client that is suitable to your requirements. creating a secure tunnel between two endpoints is well beyond the scope of a simple python script, unless you import libraries that themselves create an encrypted tunnel.

Comment: Maybe Syncthing could be for you. It probably doesn’t do _exactly_ what you need, but it already solves the entire data transfer story. Securely.

Answer (score 1):

You can do file-sharing over the internet, by creating network shares
and making them visible over the internet. No third-party product is
required, or Python, only setting correctly the router.

Opening file-sharing over the internet requires port-forwarding 4 ports
from the router to your computer
([link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc731402(v=ws.11)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)).
(I would recommend using a very good password for all your
network shares.)

You may find the public IP address of your router by using services
such as
[whatismyipaddress](https://whatismyipaddress.com/)
or its
[alternatives](http://www.moreofit.com/similar-to/whatismyipaddress.com/Top_10_Sites_Like_Whatismyipaddress/),
which your friend can use to connect to your shares.

Your problem would be that the public IP address of your router may
change in time (unless your ISP gives you a static one).
You may avoid this problem by using a Dynamic DNS server such as
[Dynu](https://www.dynu.com/). Your router may be able to do this
for you. This will let your friend connect to your computer using
a name, rather than an IP address.

Answer (score 0):

### Concept:

To copy files, ssh / scp from one computer to the other; where the "other" has to be running "sshd". This is assuming nothing (e.g. firewalls, NAT, ...) in between the computers stops this from working.

### General description:

A [raspberry pi](https://www.raspberrypi.com/products/raspberry-pi-4-model-b/) (€35+) has a simple setup to activate the provided sshd, just run the configuration tool and set it to "activated".

Find a spare hard disk and mount it in a [USB-interfaced box](https://www.google.com/search?q=external%20hdd%20case%20usb) (€20?). Connect that to the raspberry, and create an entry in the /etc/fstab file to have it be "mounted" at startup.

[Create users](https://www.google.com/search?q=adduser%20linux) in the raspberry for every person who is to have access.
These users has to be in a "[group](https://www.google.com/search?q=addgroup%20linux)", the group must have read AND write access to the hard disk.

Now; find a suitable [ssh client](https://www.google.com/search?q=ssh%20client) for each computer from which you wish to access the raspberry-hard disk, learn how to use e.g. `scp` to copy files to/from the hard disk.

NOTE NOW: Doing this with computers connected **to the same router** is fairly easy, to achieve the same with the internet in between is **likely** to be harder.
What hardships there may be is hard to tell, it might depend heavily on the Internet service provider(s) AND router(s) you use.

Comment: This is overkill - smb/windows filesharing or sshd on one side (and maybe a vpn) is all thats needed if you assume at least 1 side is not behind CGN. There is no need to build a NAS.

Comment: Overkill? I see it as a fun / learning / optional choice. Not for any other than the OP to decide.

Comment: save for the statement "I dont want to use any other 3rd party series" in the original post and the additional €55 + hard drive + power supply + case cost to achieve the same thing you can do on a computer for free.

Comment: Take it as a fun project; at low cost, especially if you already *have* a Pi and an old HDD. There are cheaper USB-boxes if you must reduce cost.